# C++: const char * to stringstream

Tags: c++

Is it possible to put a const char* into a string stream?

I think it's possible with the write() function in stringstream but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the streamsize if i only know of the const char *.

Assuming size is my const char * variable:

```
stringstream s;
s.write(temp,size);
```

How do I get size? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe with: const char* token = "HELLO WORLD!"; s.write( token, strlen( token ));

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tested it, and it works correctly...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream s;
    const char* token = "HELLO";
    s << token;
    cout << s.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}

[facu@arch ~]$ g++ p.cpp 
[facu@arch ~]$ ./a.out 
HELLO
```

Comment: That was simple. Thanks, I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: you're welcome! Check my comment in your question, maybe will be useful, i don't know if that is the best way, but worked correctly too..

Comment: This works as long as the data pointed to by the `char*` is textual (i.e. has no embedded nulls); if the data potentially has embedded nulls, as would be the case in your other thread, this will truncate the data.

Comment: Exactly, if the "string" contains "\0", example: "HELLO\0WORLD", s will contain only "HELLO"...

Comment: If I used s.write( token, strlen( token )); instead of operator << will it also result in the same behavior -- removing the embedded nulls?

Comment: The length of a C string is determined by the terminating null-character... Strings in C++ terminate with the null-character... So, if you only have got "HELLO WORLD\0" you won't have got problems... if you prove strlen( "HELLO\0WORLD" ) it will return size = 5

Comment: In the case of "Hello\0WORLD", is there a way to ignore all embedded nulls and store the whole string into a stream?

Comment: But doesn't this cause the data to be copied into an internal buffer?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes exactly. This works because `std::string` has a converting constructor from `char*`. There is no constructor of `std::stringstream` which takes a char*.  So this is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding correctly, but I think you're asking how to get the size of a `char*` string.  To do that, all you need is `strlen(str)` which is in the `<cstring>` header.  The string must be null terminated, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best way to answer your question, but see:

```
std::string _getline_ ( const char *str, const unsigned int ui_size )
{
    std::string tmp;
    unsigned short int flag = 0;
    while ( flag < 2 )
    {
    if( *str != '\0' )
    {
        tmp.push_back( *str );
        flag = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp.push_back( ' ' );
        flag++;
    }
    str++;  
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

The problem is that "flag" will store two of "\0" no more... I don't know what is your proposite.. But i hope it will be useful for you... Maybe someone wanna fix it...